# References for Algebraic number theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I am doing algebraic number theory first time. I have done all ring theory and field theory. I am interested in algebra , so also pretty much excited about algebraic number theory. I have a month's break before my semester begins. I want to self study some beginner's text covering my syllabus so that in class I can understand it much better, and may be it will turn up a research interest for me. Can somebody please suggest me some wonderful text for beginners in algebraic number theory, I do not want any number theory book using analytical methods. Strictly algebraic. Here are my contents...

> Course Outline
>
> Characteristic and minimal polynomial of an element relative to a
> finite extension, Equivalent definitions of norm and trace, Algebraic
> numbers, algebraic integers and their properties.
>
> Integral bases, discriminant, Stickelberger’s theorem, Brille’s
> theorem, description of integral basis of quadratic, cyclotomic and
> special cubic fields.
>
> Ideals in the ring of algebraic integers and their norm, factorization
> of ideals into prime ideals, generalised Fermat’s theorem and Euler’s
> theorem.
>
> Dirichlet’s theorem on units, regulator of an algebraic number fields,
> explicit computation of fundamental units in real quadratic fields.
>
> Dedekind’s theorem for decomposion of rational primes in algebraic
> number fields and its application, splitting of rational primes in
> quadratic and cyclotomic fields.

Any book that covers all these with best conceptual approach. Thanks!

Anyways here are some suggested readings by my institute-

Saban Alaca and Kenneth Williams, Introductory Algebraic Number Theory, Cambridge University Press (2003).

M. Ram Murty and J. Esmonde Problems in Algebraic Numbers Theory, Springer-Verlag (2004).

Erich Hecke, Lectures on the Theory of Algebraic Numbers, Springer-Verlag (1981).

Paula Ribenboim, Algebraic Numbers, John Wiley & Sons (1972).

Harry Pollard and Harold Diamond, The Theory of Algebraic Numbers, Dover Publications (2010).

Which one I should go for among them,  or is there some other than these all, please suggest if any? Thanks!

Comment: See :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350149/reference-request-for-algebraic-number-theory-sources-for-self-study/961934#961934

Comment: Paula Ribenboim? Surely that Paulo? Anyway, I don't know if there's a single book that covers all the topics you want, But the Marcus Book is pretty good, as is Stewart and Tall.

Comment: Saban Alaca and Kenneth Williams Looks good to start with..

Comment: I couldn't resist advertising Pierre Samuel's Algebraic Theory of Numbers. It's a very slim book so you can easily cover a lot in a month's time. Some of the proofs are really very elegant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beginner's text for Algebraic Number Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66086/beginners-text-for-algebraic-number-theory)

Answer (score -2):

Serge Lang's. Algebraic Number Theory is a good text also.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a list of recommended texts from my institute
K. Ireland and M. Rosen, A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory, 2nd Edition, Springer-Verlag, Berlin,
1990.S. Lang, Algebraic Number Theory, Addison- Wesley,
1970.D. A. Marcus, Number Fields, Springer-Verlag, 1977.